# How do I prevent unnecessary resource-load when I create new HTML elements?

Tags: html

Update:

Finally, I guess I was asking a stupid question. The jQuery creates DOM elements and it will be requested anyway. So I think it's better to use `.html(xxx)` to implement the feature rather than using `$()` to create anything before.

---

This is quite tricky and I never realize it before. But today I realized it's very important to a web project.

Say I have two images created dynamically:

```
var $img1 = $('<img>');
$img1.attr('src', 'http://domain.com/1.png');

var $img2 = $('<img>');
$img2.attr('src', 'http://domain.com/2.png');
```

Right after the browser runs the code above, the two images would be requested. That would be a waste of the client's and the server-side traffic.

Is it possible for me to control when the resource request be sent?

My expectation is NOT to do it by assigning `src` later because in my case it'd be much more complicated, the HTML code is containing a lot of stuff rather than some `img` tags. For example, is it possible to tell the browser that "please wait until the img tag is added onto the DOM tree"?

Comment: It is possible, but under what conditions would you want to change the behavior of image loading?

Comment: edited the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to load all images after all texts are loaded, right? But sorry, it is impossible.

Answer (score -3):

Append the images to DOM after the page load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    // You could use whatever jQuery selector here you like to
    // determine where to append the new elements.
    // For this example, I am just appending to end of document.
    $(document).append($('<img src="http://domain.com/1.png>');
    $(document).append($('<img src="http://domain.com/2.png>');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more? This seems like a very low quality answer.